# How to send and receive data from electron desktop app to a php website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, electron

I am an intern at nodejs and php developer..
I want to check my desktop application availability by verifying macaddress in the database of a php website.I tried sending data from app using `href="xyz.com?name=abc"`. it loads this page in the desktop application, but I can not go back to html page of the app with some returning value.Can go back to app html page with `window.history.back()`, but it can not retrieve any value, other functions search the page in website `directory.like window.location.href()`. 
I also tried ajax in the html page of application , it also not working..

HTML page in electron application..

```
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p id="ptext"></p>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="value" value="abc">
  <button id="start">start</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> console.log('hello');
  // document.getElementById('ptext').innerHtml =  window.location.search();
  $(document).ready(function{
    console.log('started document');
    $('#start').click(function{
      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      alert(formdata);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: formData,
        url: "http://localhost/newproject/index.php",
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
          $('#ptext').append(data)
        },
         error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            $('#ptext').append('Error: ' + errorMessage)
          }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Php website page

```
<?php 
$val = $_GET['value'];
echo "\n".$val;
if($val=='abc')
    {
?>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">window.history.back();</script>
 --><?php 
        echo "\nright value";
    }
else
    {
        echo "\nwrong value";
    }
// echo "\n".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; -------> does Not have any value , undefined
// header("location:index.html?result==right/wrong") -----> it search this page in website directory
 ?>
```

Now , how do I return some data to nodejs electron application. 
It will be a great help for my project.
Thank you everyone for having a look at my first question on this website.

Comment: I would try to use 1.) an API route that PHP can perform at POST to (passing in data), or 2.) -- probably overkill and the wrong option to pursue -- a socket connection from node.js (using socket.io) that 'listens' for data sent by PHP maybe?

Comment: Try using fetch or Node module for request such as axios or needle.